# Using PL/SQL in ODI or OBIEE?

Tags: plsql, obiee, oracle-data-integrator

I have one question, in which step we can use PL/SQL in Oracle Business Intelligence: the ELT ODI or in OBIEE, and for what exactly?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

you can use a pl/sql code in `ODI`  you can use a component called `Procedures` you can find it in Designer tab as bellow a link for more information 
[use Pl/Sql in ODI](http://odiexperts.com/how-to-use-plsql-procedures-and-functions-in-odi/)